# android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE - Como atribuir permissão de sistema?

Tags: android, android-permission

Pessoal preciso usar no meu App a seguinte permissão:

```
android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE
```

Porém mostra um erro no Manifest dizendo que a permissão somente é concedida a apps de sistema.

Preciso interceptar a ligação, afim de desliga-la e enviar um sms para o número.

Preciso torna-lo app de sistema, mas como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente não é possível mais obter essa permissão. A partir do Android 2.3+ essa permissão foi limitada a apenas aplicativos do sistema.

Na própria [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MODIFY_PHONE_STATE) é citada que não é para uso de terceiros.

Como podemos ver no [commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f4ece2086f3b7060edc4b93a12f04c9af648867a) feito pelo David Brown, contribuidor do Android, a permissão foi marcada como `signatureOrSystem`.

Existem alguns issues, por exemplo [15031](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15031), [15022](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15022) e [14789](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14789) . Eles foram ignorados.

Como alternativa você poderia instalar seu App como sendo do sistema, porém é um processo manual e que necessita de root para funcionar.

Answer (score 4):

Essa permissão é apenas para aplicações de sistema!

**Nenhuma outra aplicação pode utilizar esta permissão a não ser a do sistema.**

O que você precisa fazer?

Comment: Editei a pergunta -- preciso interceptar a ligação.

Comment: Você não pode tornar a sua aplicação do sistema só com hack e se o seu aplicativo tem âmbito de ser publicado não vai funcionar pois cada cliente teria que hackear o próprio android para funcionar!

Quanto ao que você precisa.. tem como fazer e não precisa dessa permissão! Quando chegar em casa posto um exemplo pra vc!

Comment: Oh legal Trxplz0 ficaria agradecido! :)